# problem with @use in scss file Yii2 advanced

Tags: sass, yii2

i'm stuck with scss and yii2
i have `common.scss` where i include another two files `_theme.scss` and `_variables.scss`
here is what my `common.scss` looks like:

```
@use 'variables';
@use 'theme';
```

all three files are in the same folder

this is my component configuration

```
'assetManager' => [
    'converter' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\AssetConverter',
        'commands' => [
            'less' => ['css', 'sass {from} {to} --source-map'],
        ],
    ],
],
```

this is my frontend AppAsset file content

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/common.scss',
        ['css/print.css', 'media' => 'print'],
    ];
    public $js = [];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap5\BootstrapAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap5\BootstrapPluginAsset'
    ];
}
```

now when i've added below line to `_variables.scss`

```
$color-orange:#f6861f;
```

and try to use it in `_theme.scss` like this

```
.text-lc-orange {
    color:#{$orange};
}
```

nothing happens
any glues?